# Non Azure VPS connecting to Azure SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, vps

Ive got a VPS running a web application where its performance is being slowed incredibly by the SQL Server that is installed alongside it.  I want to use Azure SQL Server to host the database there and the Application on the VPS that is external to Azure.

Ive published the Database and its data to Azure nicely from the VPS, added the IP address of the VPS on the allowed connection list in the firewall, however when I go to use the connectionstring, I get the usual no permissions or Database does not exist..

Im relatively new to Azure services (Used visual studio to connect and configured virtual machines etc..)so what more do I need to do in order to allow this External VPS to connect and access the SQL Server on Azure?

Comment: Have you tried adding your own IP address and connecting to the server with SSMS?

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault. That said: Be sure to check your connection string format, and make sure it matches what's required for SQL Database service.

Comment: @Stijn          Yes, I get login failed...  :-(  I am on a the free trail currently does that make a difference?  Am I missing soething and do I have to create a virtual machine?

Comment: have you tested the database connection with application on your local system (localhost). Please also check ping of your SQL Azure connection or telnet the SQL Azure.

Comment: @KaiMarkhirst - free trials work 100% like any other Azure subscription.